# pyinotify can not watch current dir

Tags: python, pyinotify

I put a script using pyinotify under my home dir (/home/name) and run it. While I can not make the script watch my home dir (/home/name) or dirs that contain my home dir, like root (/) and /home/. All other dirs are OK, like /var, /boot, /home/name/Documents.

Let me describe it in a clean way:

```
dirs that are NOT OK:
/
/home
/home/name (script is here)

All other dirs are OK, e.g.
/bin
/var
/home/name/Documents
```

**Script:**

```
import pyinotify

class MyEventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_ACCESS(self, event):
        print "ACCESS event:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_ATTRIB(self, event):
        print "ATTRIB event:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE(self, event):
        print "CLOSE_NOWRITE event:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        print "CLOSE_WRITE event:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        print "CREATE event:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_DELETE(self, event):
        print "DELETE event:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print "MODIFY event:", event.pathname

    def process_IN_OPEN(self, event):
        print "OPEN event:", event.pathname

def main():
    # watch manager
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
    wm.add_watch('/var/log', pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS, rec=True)

    # event handler
    eh = MyEventHandler()

    # notifier
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, eh)
    notifier.loop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What error are you getting (e.g. "Errno=Permission denied (EACCES)")? What are the directory permissions?

Comment: no output, and it's my home dir. I have all permissions. I pasted the script above.

Comment: You will need to add a watch to home.

Comment: Perhaps these directories have an unusual ACL set -- try "getfacl /home". What OS and version? Is your home on an NFS or CIFS server?

Answer (score 1):

Think you need to specify a watch to your home dir.

```
wm.add_watch('/home', pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS, rec=True)
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I might have confused you. I know I need to specify the path. I have tried the following paths: '/home', '/', '/home/<my name>', '/var/log', '/boot', but the script could not work with first three paths.